# Dynamically create sprite sheets in production web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, css-sprites

In an app I've built we display a lot of small images. During page load, these images flicker in as all the individual web requests complete

Normally I use Compass to compile my sprite sheets at build time to cut down on the number of requests. However, in this case the images are user provided, there are thousands of them, and they change frequently. For now they are uploaded to S3 and served through CDN along with the other user provided content.

I'm weighing the benefits of generating specific and focused sprite sheets on the fly, per request. Or maybe build base64-inline stylesheets?

Has anyone tried this before, or know of a tool that solves this problem?

Comment: If you build them on request (so that each one could be different?) that feels a bit like defeating some of the purpose of having them at all.  Could you group the graphics together and build the sprite sheets "offline", eg in a scheduled rake task?  Or are there so many different graphics that it's impossible to usefully group them?

Comment: Btw i've never used it but this looks potentially relevant https://github.com/jakesgordon/sprite-factory

Comment: A rake task would probably work - although there is a giant number of images, and they change frequently, so I'd have to be clever about the scheduling. My thought was that building and cacheing the sheets on demand would be a little bit more stable.

Comment: I would probably use something like sprite-factory to do the actual sprite-building. Though I hadn't seen that tool, thanks for the link

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compass gem compiles your images into a sprite when precompiling assets. Might be worth a look

Comment: Hi Jon, I already use compass for my sprites at build time. These images are user-provided, so they are not available at build time.

Comment: I was thinking that it (ie building a sprite sheet on demand) might slow your response down, though, thus counteracting the speed benefit of using sprite sheets in the first place.  If they do change really frequently then maybe it's not suitable for sprite sheet caching at all?  Either way i guess you'd need some logic for detecting when a change has occurred and rebuilding the sprite sheet, though thinking about it some more this would probably be best done in a Resque-style background worker after the user uploads a new image (or does whatever they do that updates the image).

Comment: Max you might be right on that; I guess what I like about the endpoint is that there is no "moving around" the files. If I serve the sprite sheet through my controller then it will immediately go into CDN and I don't have to worry about managing all the sprite sheets and related CSS that I'll be generating.

Comment: But I might end up using a background job for this.